# How to switch to a specific directory before grepping in emacs?

Tags: emacs, grep, working-directory

I am grepping across all my projects:

```
(defun grep-all-projects(start end)
  (interactive "r")
  (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active)
      (setq my-word (buffer-substring-no-properties start end))
    (setq my-word (thing-at-point 'word))
    )
  (let ((default-directory (getenv "REPOS_DIR")))
    (message "===> Grepping '%s' in %s" my-word (getenv "REPOS_DIR"))
    (grep (format "grep --exclude-dir target -r -ne '%s' ." my-word)))
  )
```

But somehow the grepping is performed on the root directory (`/`), even though the grep buffer correctly says:

```
-*- mode: grep; default-directory: "/repos/" -*-
Grep started at Tue Jun  6 10:38:08
```

What is going on? Is `emacs` `grep` not respecting the `default-directory`?

### EDIT

This workaround, without making use of `default-directory`, works:

```
(defun grep-all-projects(start end)
  (interactive "r")
  (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active)
      (setq my-word (buffer-substring-no-properties start end))
    (setq my-word (thing-at-point 'word))
    )
  (message "===> Grepping '%s' in %s" my-word (getenv "REPOS_DIR"))
  (grep (format "grep --exclude-dir target -r -ne '%s' %s" my-word (getenv "REPOS_DIR")))
  )
```

I am still interested in knowing why the first implementation does not work as expected

Comment: What tells you that `grep` is working from the root (`/`)?  If the `*grep*` buffer says the `default-directory` is `/repos/` then that's the default directory.

Comment: @Drew I see it grepping on the root directory: it takes forever, and it complains that it can not grep in directories like `/var`, because of missing rights.

Answer (score 0):

`M-x cd` changes to a directory you input. It changes the value of buffer-local variable `default-directory`.  `C-h f cd` tells you:

> **`cd`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `files.el`.
>
> `(cd DIR)`
>
> Make DIR become the current buffer's default directory.
>
> If your environment includes a `CDPATH` variable, try each one of
>   that list of directories (separated by occurrences of
>   `path-separator`) when resolving a relative directory name.
>   The path separator is colon in GNU and GNU-like systems.